# Binding dictionary values to ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

I set the key/value as:

```
dict["Error"], dict["StartTime"], dict["ConnectedTime"] and dict["DialingResult"]
```

Also in code behind `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
ObservableCollection<Calls> items = new ObservableCollection<Calls>();
```

About `Calls` class,

```
public class Calls : NotifyUIBase  // NotifyUIBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string dialResult;
    public string DialResult {
        get { return dialResult; }
        set
        {
            dialResult = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string dialError;
    public string DialError
    {
        get { return dialError; }
        set
        {
            dialError = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string startTime;
    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
        set
        {
            startTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string connectedTime;
    public string ConnectedTime
    {
        get { return connectedTime; }
        set
        {
            connectedTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string dialingResult;
    public string DialingResult
    {
        get { return dialingResult; }
        set
        {
            dialingResult = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to display each value in the window. I assume the primary code likely

```
   <DockPanel>
        <ItemsControl Height="300" Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding Calls}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl></DockPanel>
```

In MainWindow:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
```

To update the control, we have

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new BackgroundProcess(args).RunScript();
Calls c = new Calls();
// if no error:
c.startTime = dict["StartTime"];
c.connectedTime = dict["ConnectedTime"];
c.DialResult =  dict["DialingResult"];
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        items.Add(c);
    });
```

In my code I have

```
Binding Path=Value
```

It perhaps wrong. I don't know how to binding the values correctly.

Comment: You're not binding to `Dictionary`. You set `ItemsSource` to `ObservableCollection<Calls>` so each item will be of `Call` type and that does not have `Value` property. In your case `Path` can be any public property of `Call` class as that's `DataContext` behind each item

Comment: @dkozl, my dictionary `dict` is not in code behind. It is in another class for background process, how to bind it?

Comment: As dkolz said, you're binding to a collection of objects of type `Calls` so your DataTemplate is operating with its context. There is no **Value** property, only DialResult, DialError, StartTime, ConnectedTime and DialingResult. What would you like to display? Give us an example.

Comment: @Jerrington, I want to display the values line by line. Say first line is for ` DialError`, then second line is for `StartTime`, the third line is for `ConnectedTime` and the fouth line is for `DialingResult`.

Comment: Why not add more `TextBlocks` then and each will be bound to a different property i.e. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DialError, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="0"/>` and so forth. You'd probably have to add a `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` sections so each `TextBlock` has its own row.

Comment: I obviously meant `Grid.RowDefinitions` sections ;)

Comment: @Jerrington, I used the d.moncada's method. But why it only occupied a small portion space? I think * (star) take as much space as available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting ItemsSource twice.

Once here:

```
 <ItemsControl Height="300" Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding Calls}">
```

And the other time here:

```
   icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Also, you are not technically binding to a 'dictionary' since you are just getting the values within the Dictionary and putting them into the `ObservableCollection`.

Also, what type of information from the Calls class do you want to display? If you want to display each property from the ObservableCollection, you can do so (via code behind like you have it) like this:

```
<DockPanel>
        <ItemsControl Height="300" Name="icTodoList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialResult, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialError, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectedTime, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialingResult, FallbackValue=' '}" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

What the ItemsControl is doing is being bound to the ObservableCollection via code-behind. Then, each property within the Calls class is bound to a TextBlock since the scope of each item is of type Calls.

Side note: You may want to look into MVVM to do this instead, and you typically do not want to do this stuff via code-behind.

Comment: So you are not binding the dictionary, you use the trick to overwrite the properties?

Comment: @Love, you're populating your `Calls` object's values from your dictionary so there's not point binding to it. You've got all you need in your `Calls` object.

Comment: I want to stretch the result out from left to right, now it only display partial result. Maybe the column width is wrong?

Comment: @Love, which properties do you not see? I just updated it (the column set was wrong due to a copy/paste error).

Comment: I up voted it and I marked it as the answer. But if you could improve it, it would be great. I only want one column but different rows. Each row binding one property. So I have enough width.

Comment: Okay, I can do that. So, how many items are inside the observable collection?